# Defer triggering a GitHub action until all prerequisites have completed

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have this GitHub Action which should work only after three other Actions have completed. I have configured it this way:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Extrae usuario y repo","Nombre contenedor Docker","Crea artefacto con configuración"]
```

The problem is I have noticed that it triggers after *every* one of them has run, not when all three of them have completed. Is there any way to create this graph-based hooks in GitHub Actions? Alternatively, I guess I could just skip running until the goods (some artifacts) have already been created.

Comment: Could they be jobs *within* a workflow? Then you can use [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

Comment: No, they can't. It's a complicated workflow, with one initial one triggering two others, which then feed on a 4th workflow. Push come to shove, I guess I could, but really they do different things at different points in development, so this modularity is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. You need kind of orchestration for that, like outside stateful app which is aware what was already run, and once you condition passed fire another workflow.

With `workflow_run` your workflow every time one of the listed workflow completes..